# Trying to solve a simple matrix multiplication operation but getting a single error

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I am just trying to use the result of one function into the other and do a simple matrix multiplication. The first function(M2N) is working fine but 2nd function psht is showing error. This is the code:

```matlab
    M2N.m:
    % 1D PSHT Matlab code
    function M=M2N(n)
    n=2;
    B=4;
    if n==1
    M=eye(2);
    else
    p=2^(n-1)-2; m=2^(2*n-2);
    a=sqrt(3*m/(4*m-B)) ; b=sqrt((m-B)/(4*m-B));
    M=[[1 0 ;0 b] zeros(2,p) [0 0;a 0] zeros(2,p);
    zeros(p,2) eye(p) zeros(p,2) zeros(p,p);
    [0 0 ; 0 a] zeros(2,p) [0 1 ;-b 0] zeros(2,p);
    zeros(p,2) zeros(p,p) zeros(p,2) eye(p)];
    end
    end

    psht.m:
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    function Y=psht()
    n=2;
    for i=1:n
    Y=kron(eye(2^(n-i)),M2N(i))* kron(eye(2^(n-i)),kron(hadamard(2),eye(2^(i- 
    1))))*Y;
    end
    end
```

This is the error:

[image: Error is shown here]

Comment: It is difficult to read the code. Try to use intermediate variable for better code visibility. For example, you can create a temporary variable equals to kron(eye(2^(n-i)),M2N(i)).

Comment: That is not the full error message. MATLAB always produces very detailed error messages. Please copy-paste the full error message into your question — don’t post a screen shot.

Comment: Y is undefined prior to your assignment on that line.